# How to Delete Rows That Contains Some Text in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I want to drop some rows in my that contain some text.

```
Date      Campaign
3/24/20   GA Shoes Search Campaign
3/24/20   GA Shoes Display Campaign
3/24/20   GA Bag Search Campaign
3/24/20   GA Bag Display Campaign
3/24/20   IG Shoes Campaign
3/24/20   IG Bag Campaign
3/24/20   FB Shoes Campaign
3/24/20   FB Bag Campaign
3/24/20   Email Campaign
```

I want to delete all rows and leave the rows that contain GA. Here's the result I want:

```
Date      Campaign
3/24/20   GA Shoes Search Campaign
3/24/20   GA Shoes Display Campaign
3/24/20   GA Bag Search Campaign
3/24/20   GA Bag Display Campaign
```

I tried to do this:

```
mask = df['Campaign'].str.contains('FB')
idx = df.index[mask]
new = df.drop(idx,axis=0)
```

However, it only works if I do one string at a time. I tried to do this to save time, but it didn't work:

```
mask = df['Campaign'].str.contains('FB', 'Email', 'IG')
idx = df.index[mask]
new = df.drop(idx,axis=0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than dropping the rows that contain the other letters, you could just apply a function to grab the rows that *do* contain 'GA' :

`new = df[df['Campaign'].apply(lambda x: 'GA' in x)]`

Answer (score 3):

The assumption here is that for all relevant rows, `GA` is at the start of the sentence. Pandas str [startswith](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) can help here:

```
df.loc[df.Campaign.str.startswith("GA")]

    Date    Campaign
0   3/24/20 GA Shoes Search Campaign
1   3/24/20 GA Shoes Display Campaign
2   3/24/20 GA Bag Search Campaign
3   3/24/20 GA Bag Display Campaign
```

If however, `GA` might be embedded within the sentence and not at the very beginning, it would be helpful if you provided data similar to that. That way, it can be determined if `GA` is within words, or on its own, or whatever, and hopefully find a solution that fits

Comment: Hi sammywemmy, what if GA has other variations like ZGA, can I do df.loc[df.Campaign.str.startswith("GA", "ZGA)]? Or would it only work one at time?

Comment: @ssmm, for multiple entries in `startswith`, use a tuple : `df.loc[df.Campaign.str.startswith(("GA", "ZGA"))]`

Answer (score 1):

## Setup example dataframe

If you have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['A0', 'A1', 'B2', 'A3'],
                   'y': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                   'z': ['A0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                   'w': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
                    index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Which looks like:

[image]

and let's say, you want to create those rows which contain `A` in column `x`.

---

## Methods

## [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

You can do:

```
df[df['x'].str.contains('A')]
```

---

## [List comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it/34932520)

`df[['A' in each for each in df['x']]]` will suffice.

---

## [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

If you are into [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), can do:

```
df[df['x'].apply(lambda x: 'A' in x)]
```

---

## Results

All of these methods will give you:

[image]

---

**Final notes**
More generally speaking:

- The [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method:

`df[df[name_of_column_which_should_contain_something].str.contains(what_should_it_contain)]`

- The [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it/34932520) method:

  `df[[what_to_search_for in each for each in df[whichcolumn]]]`
- The [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method:

  `df[df[which_column_to_search_in].apply(lambda x: what_to_search_for in x)]`

Comment: I got an error that said: "unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'". Here's the code: df1[df1['Order'].str.contains('FB','Email', 'IG')]

Comment: Hmm, for which method did you get that error? (Maybe try the others?)